# Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem - Detail omitted in proof

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1_{\{X_i(\omega)\le x\}}$ be the empirical distribution function for iid. random variables $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $\Omega$. Denote the distribution function of $X_i$ as $F(x)$. 
Important: Note that both $F_n$ and $F$ will in the following be viewed as *functions of* $\omega$ for *fixed* $x$.

In the GC Theorem it is shown that
$$P(\{ \omega\in\Omega\colon \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|F_n(x)(\omega)-F(x)(\omega)|=0\})=1$$

I have seen some proofs of it, but nobody ever proofs that $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|F_n(x)(\omega)-F(x)(\omega)|$$
as a function of $\omega$ is actually measurable.

What is obvious is that $F_n(\omega)$ is measurable. I would then proceed to prove that $F$ is meausurable and then the supremum of the absolute value. But I cannot show those things.

Does anyone see how to proof measurability?

Comment: Hint: What if the sup was taken over $\mathbb Q$ instead?

Comment: What is $X$ here?

Comment: @Sam Without a rigorous argument, I would assume it would be the same supremum, because of the epsilon property of the supremum. This would help a lot, because for countable many numbers I know that the supremum is measurable. Now it just remains to show that $F$ is measurable which was the hardest problem for me, since $F$ is not necessarily defined on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta  $F$ is the distribution function of the $X_i$'s, why do you say it's not well defined on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal{B})$?

Comment: @Sam Remember that we want to prove the measurability of $F(\omega)$ with $x$ fixed. Now $X_i$ may be real-valued, but its domain $\Omega$ may not be real. E.g. we need the measurability of $F(\omega)\colon \Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$ for any fixed $x$.

Comment: For each $x\in\mathbb R$, $F(x)$ is a number, not a function, so the expressions $F(\omega)$ or $F(x)(\omega)$ don't make sense. The function you are trying to prove measurable is $G(\omega) =\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|F_n(x)(\omega) - F(x)|$. For each fixed $x$ this is clearly a measurable function defined on $\Omega$, so all that's left to prove is that the sup over $\mathbb R$ is the same as the sup over $\mathbb Q$.